# How to inject hk2 servicelocator in a jersey jax-rs app

Tags: jersey, interceptor, hk2

I am migrating a legacy service framework that uses java serialization/reflection to register services and call them as remote endpoints (javabin over http) or local calls seamlessly.
I have replaced the remote calls as jersey endpoints. Also used hk2 aop based interceptor to recreate some of the interception abilities of current framework. It is working fine when remote client makes a call to the endpoint.
Now I need to do the same for local calls to service methods and be able to use the **same intercept logic** as the remote service method calls.

(implemented org.glassfish.hk2.api.InterceptionService - based on this article - https://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/01/21/intercepting-jersey-resource-method-calls/)

I believe if I am able to get the instance of service(jax-rs resource) class from hk2 registry/locator, then method calls will invoke the same registered interceptors. How to achieve it?

Comment: Just inject it like you would any other service `@Inject ServiceLocator locator`

Comment: thanks, injecting works and the registered instance can be retrieved. Interceptors are invoked for jvm-local invocations too. `service=locator.getAllServiceHandles(<Restservice>.class, new Annotation[0]);service.callInterceptedMethod();`

Comment: A related tip - while using hk2 ServiceLocator in a raw HttpServer without jersey - registered the bound the services in singleton scope but got following error while materializing the service - <br/>  "A service  needs either method or constructor interception, but proxies are not available" <br/> The reason was Utilities.proxiesAvailable returning false since javassist jar was not in classpath. javassist is a mandatory dependency for hk2 if you want to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

As said by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/paul-samsotha) in the comments you can always just @Inject or lookup the ServiceLocator.  In fact, it's the service with the lowest ID (the first service added to the hk2 system).

In the case of children locators you will normally get the child ServiceLocator before the parent ServiceLocator unless you do something very specific with your query.  This is because the rule for duplicate services is to pick the one with the highest locator id (which will be the child one)